# Why there is no LastOrDefault method in petapoco like FirstOrDefault?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, petapoco

Let's say this is my table `TicketUpdate` in SQL Server with some data inside:

```
_______________________________
| Id | TicketId | Description |
-------------------------------
| 1  |   5      |   desc1     |
| 2  |   6      |   desc2     |
| 3  |   5      |   desc3     |
| 4  |   5      |   desc4     |
| 5  |   6      |   desc5     |
```

I want to retrieve the last row with `TicketId = 5` in using `Petapoco`.

There are several methods for retrieving single row like `FirstOrDefault` which looks like:

```
db.FirstOrDefault<TicketUpdate>("select * from TicketUpdate where TicketId = 5");
```

But using this statement it returns the first row with value of `TicketId = 5` with a description of `desc1`.

My question is how can I retrieve the `LastOrDefault` value then? There is no such methods in Petapoco.

**Additional info**

Temporarily I can retrieve the last row with `TicketId = 5` by nesting the query like

```
select * 
from TicketUpdate 
where Id = (select MAX(Id) from TicketUpdate where TicketId = 5)
```

But is there any methods or better approach for finding the last row like we retrieve First row by using `FirstOrDefault` method, without nesting the query?

Comment: Asking for "first" or "last" when you don't specify an *order* is effectively "give me a random row". If you *do* specify an order, you don't need `LastOrDefault` - or, in fact, you do already have `LastOrDefault`. It's spelled `FirstOrDefault` but you use the opposite order than you used previously.

Comment: I have to agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever. The table itself is not ordered, unless you specify the order manually. Therefore LastOrDefault() would not make sense. Instead you can use OrderByDesc(...).FirstOrDefault().

Comment: `select * from TicketUpdate where TicketId = 5 order by ID desc`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, you should be able to sort your data first.
Try something like this:

```
db.FirstOrDefault<TicketUpdate>("select TOP 1 * from TicketUpdate where TicketId = 5 orderby [Id] desc");
```

As long as `Id` is incremented it should return the last item added for `TicketId == 5`.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, I already fixed it, But the first credit goes to Damien_The_Unbeliever. any way thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to get the last record where ID is `max`. Also you need to use `Top 1` to get only one record.

```
select Top 1 * from TicketUpdate where TicketId = 5 order by ID desc
```

Comment: thank you, But I fixed it immediately after Damien_The_Unbeliever commented, Really my mind was hanged, I even didn't think about ordering, So it's my mistake.. Anyway thanks